# How do I pass a function parameter into a lambda function subsequently

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to pass in the `timeframe='month'` parameter into my function. I tried applying with lambda function but it doesn't seem to work.

```
def a(query_date=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2016-12-31']), timeframe = 'month'):
  a = query_date.to_series().apply(lambda x:x.timeframe)
  print(a)
```

Any advice on how to apply my timeframe inside? I want to able to extract the day, month or year with a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that by using the dunder method `__getattribute__` like so:

```
def fn(query_date=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2016-12-31']), timeframe = 'month'):
    a = query_date.to_series().apply(lambda x: x.__getattribute__(timeframe))
    return a
print(fn())
```

Comment: I don't get the point here ^^ Isn't that just a convoluted way to say `pd.DatetimeIndex(['2016-12-31']).month`?

Comment: @MrFuppes I don't understand either. You can just use strf & strptime to get the same attribute. Just giving them what they asked for. I'm guessing the code they provided is just to be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: maybe passing the desired attribute as a string gives some advantage (e.g. "month"), but then you don't need the lambda, just `dti.__getattribute__("month").to_series(index=dti)` with `dti` being the input datetime index.

Comment: @MrFuppes you're right! I can simplify without the lambda, thanks! I'm only subsidising the function to reproduce the issue.